# Android: Running app with locked screen

Tags: android, background

new to android programming. I am trying to create a very simple flashlight app in android studio and i want to be able to run the app when the phone is locked and as a background activity. I have understood that i should use Service but i can't figure out how or where to implement it in my code. 
Thank you.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //flag to detect flash is on or off
    private boolean isLightOn = false;

    private Camera camera;


    private ImageButton button;


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (camera != null) {
            camera.release();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);




        Context context = this;
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        // if device support camera?
        if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            return;
        }

        camera =  open();
        final Parameters p = camera.getParameters();

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if (isLightOn) {
                    p.setFlashMode(FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    camera.setParameters(p);
                    camera.stopPreview();
                    isLightOn = false;
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.onbuttontrans);

                } else {

                    p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    camera.setParameters(p);
                    camera.startPreview();
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.offbuttontrans);
                    isLightOn = true;

                }

            }
        });
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.g131146.flashlight" >

    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />


        <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:icon="@drawable/appicon">

            <activity
                android:label="Flashlight"
                android:name=".MainActivity">


                <intent-filter >

                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this similar issue and solved it through the following method.
Here we basically combined the code in the onPause and onStop methods. Hence you could comment out the code in there. I didn't really use any Service as this fixed the issue. Hope it helps! 
Add this in your MainActivity:

```
@Override

   public void onBackPressed() {

        super.onBackPressed();
        myParameters = myCamera.getParameters();
        myParameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        myCamera.setParameters(myParameters);
        myCamera.stopPreview();
        FlashOn = false;//this is a boolean

        if (myCamera != null) {
            myCamera.release();
            myCamera = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this may help @olle with their implementation turing the flash on the question is actually about how to set up the app so that it can be run with a locked screen, not how to implement turning on the flash.